# Probability of the hunter to shoot the target exactly 6 times

Tags: probability

> A shooter can hit a given target with probability $\dfrac{1}{4}$. She keeps firing a bullet at the
>   target until she hits it successfully three times and then she stops firing. What is the probability that she fires exactly six bullets?

I am clueless it will be appreciated if any clue is provided without writing the complete solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sixth shot must be the third hit. Two of the first five shots must be hits. So:
$$P(X=2)\cdot \frac14=\begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}\cdot \left(\frac14\right)^2\cdot \left(\frac34\right)^3\cdot \frac14=\frac{135}{2048}.$$

Comment: Can you please elaborate your process?

Comment: $P(X=2)$ is the probability of two hits out of five shots. It is the binomial distribution: $P(X=x)=\begin{pmatrix} n \\ x\end{pmatrix}\cdot p^n\cdot (1-p)^{n-x}$. And $\frac14$ is the probability of a hit. The two probabilities are multiplied as the events are independent.

Answer (score 3):

Consider what situation she would fire six bullets. She would have to hit successfully for the 3rd time on her 6th bullet. As a result, in between, she would have to hit successfully exactly 2 times; it may help to utilize the binomial distribution to calculate the probability of this component.